# UIPopovercontroller Parent?

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller

How can "perform selector" to the parentviewcontroller of the uipopovercontroller?
I have uipopovercontroller lanuched from uiviewcontroller, and this uipopovercontroller includes other uiviewcontroller.
I can't seem to reach the parent view controller from either the popover or the "internal" view controller.

I hope i'm being clear...

BTW - parentViewcontroller doesn't work...

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no way to do this directly with `UIPopoverController`. You're going to have to probably pass a reference to your parent view controller to the view controller you're managing with a popover controller:

```
// Assumes these calls are made from within a view controller and that
// MyViewController has a property called previousViewController

MyViewController * myViewController = [[[MyViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
myViewController.previousViewController = self;
UIPopoverController * popoverController = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] 
    initWithContentViewController:myViewController] autorelease];

UIBarButtonItem * rightBarButtonItem = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem;
[popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:rightBarButtonItem
                          permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown
                                          animated:YES];
```

Something like that, but the important point is that your view controller (managed by the popover controller) has to grab a reference to your parent view controller before you present the popover.

Comment: Thats exactly what i thought. If that's the only way, i will do it.
Thanks!

Comment: @AviTsadok You can use popoverController.delegate

Answer (score 0):

You can use a private method to get a parent popover controller from the view controller.

```
UIPopoverController *popopverController = [self performSelector:@selector(_popoverController)];
[popopverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```