# Running a method in main view, in response to popover Method

Tags: iphone, methods, popover

I'm trying to call a method in my main view (TapView) from a button in my popover (pop)

Now at the minute I have

```
    -(void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:
(UIPopoverController *)pop {
    [self noise];
}
```

Setup so that when the popover is dismissed it runs the method. This works, and is 'acceptable'

What I would rather have happen though is that the user presses a UIButton (let's call it...'load1' in the popover and that this calls the method instead.

Anyone got any bright ideas on this? I'm sure it's dead simple but Im not really sure 'what' it is I'm trying to do, so searching for answers has given a rather huge range of options.

EDIT: This how I'm calling my popover. That might help.

```
saveLoadScifi *sLoad = [[saveLoadScifi alloc] init];
UIPopoverController *pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:sLoad];
[pop setDelegate:self];
CGRect popoverRect = [self.view convertRect:[sender frame]
                                   fromView:[sender superview]];
[pop presentPopoverFromRect:popoverRect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your popover controller's header, add:

```
#import "TapView.h"
@property(nonatomic, assign) TapView *tapView;    // *assign* to prevent mutual retain cycle
```

Synthesize that. When you create the popover (<strike>I'm assuming somewhere in TapView.m you `alloc/init` your popover</strike> referencing the code you posted), set

```
sLoad.tapView = self;
```

after the `alloc/init`. In this case, `self` would be in the instance of TapView that you want to call a method on.

The button should invoke an action method:

```
- (IBAction)noise {
    [self.tapView noise];
}
```

Hook up that method (with a proper declaration in the header: `-(IBAction)noise;`) and you're good to go.

Comment: Getting 'Unknown type name'TapView' in the popover header any ideas why? Added sample code of how I call my popover.

Comment: My guess is that you didn't import "TapView.h"

Comment: Ah I didn't...let me try that again.

Comment: Right...it's close, I hook all that up as suggested (putting the [self.tapView noise] within an existing method as that's where it best fits) but get no response - the only thing I have is a warning that TapViewController (i.e. TapView - the controller's actually TapViewController) may not repond to 'noise'  Going to carry on exploring but thought I'd throw it out there.

EDIT: Realised I hadn't declared noise in TapView.h but I went, declared it etc and it still has the same effect but without the warning.

Comment: Ah got it, typo. Thank you the tick is yours,and with it the bounty :) Enjoy.

Comment: Bonus question: Is there an easy way that within the noise method in the TapViewController, I could also dismiss the popover? Not a huge issue but would be an awesome thing if I could do so. Have had 'answers' before but found it very tricky to work out to the point of not being able to do so.

Comment: After calling `[self.tapView noise];`, you could just call `[self dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];` in the same `noise` method in the popover.

Comment: Can't seem to get that bit to work. Putting it in the main code throws an unrecognised selector fault causing a crash. Changing it to self.tapView is equally unsuccessful. Not a big thing...just icing on cake :)

Comment: No, call it in your popover, not your `tapView`. Should fix the unrecognized selector.

Comment: Instance Method '-dimissPopoverAnimated:' not found (return type defaults to 'id') then crashes with `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[saveLoadScifi dismissPopoverAnimated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x594a340'` This is done in the popover.

Comment: Oh...oops, sorry. You need to call that method in `pop`, not `saveLoadScifi`. I recommend you hold on to it in your main view controller, then when *its* `noise` method is called, dismiss the popover by calling `[pop dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];`

Comment: Thing is, if I put it in there (which I tried) I get that pop is undeclared.

Comment: Right—you'll need to save `pop` as an instance variable. You could also lazily instantiate it: in the main view controller, use `if (!self.pop) self.pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:sLoad];`

Comment: @Inspire48 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2413/discussion-between-david26th-and-inspire48)

Answer (score 1):

Add a property to your content view controller and set it to reference the TapView instance you want to call a method on.  Then from within your content view controller you can call-back to any method you want.

This appears to be the same question, and the answer looks reasonable.

[UIPopovercontroller Parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951200/uipopovercontroller-parent)

Comment: It seems similar, I can see that it gives my TapView something to reference, and creates the popover, but I'm still unsure on how I'd set the methods up to actually fire off.